# Website contact form only sending mail to exchange inboxes

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, exchange-server, contact-form-7

I have a wordpress website which uses Contact Form 7. It's a simple setup, just name, number email and send.

On hitting Submit, the form will successfully send an email to my personal gmail address.

However, if the recipient is hosting their email on an exchange server, these emails do not come through.

I have seen this happen on a few different websites that I have hosted on my server, and each time emails do not come through to an exchange-based inbox.

Not completely versed in how various email types work so I've exhausted my own limited research into this. Hopefully somebody on here can help point me in the right direction!

Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to answer based on your info. Most likely the send mail is marked as spam. Should not be exclusively an exchange problem. You should invest the structure of your email. What is exactly in the header information and why is it marked as spam. You could try mailing to https://www.mail-tester.com/ to get a overall indication. Copy the complete header information and run an inspect. For instance by Google: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/

Comment: Thanks for your input. You are correct in that when the mail did arrive successfully in gmail, it was in the junk folder. I'll follow the steps you suggested and hopefully that will help